# Getting color codes of the current tk palette

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

In tkinter, is it possible to get the colours of the currently used palette, so that I can use them e.g. when drawing a rectangle on the canvas?

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.tk_bisque() # change the palette to bisque
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100, fill='???') # What to enter here?
```

I know I can use e.g. 'bisque' as a colour name, however the [documentation](https://man.archlinux.org/man/extra/tk/tk_bisque.n.en) speaks of a database containing entries like 'activeBackground', 'highlightColor', etcetera. I want to know how to use those as colours for my canvas items, or alternatively simply how to get their rgb values at runtime.

Comment: I dont think RGB value is accepted by `tkinter`, it should be HEX?

Comment: Hex, rgb, any format is fine as long as I can somehow know the exact colour :) (without taking a screenshot of my running application...)

Comment: You can use `root.winfo_rgb` to find the RGB for a given color, but I don't think there is any inverse to the `setPalette` function.  If you do `root.cget('bg')`, it tells you the name of the background color, and `winfo_rgb` can tell you its RGB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `root.option_get(name, '.')` to get the default colors of the widget:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.tk_bisque() # change the palette to bisque
print(root.option_get('background', '.'))
print(root.option_get('activeBackground', '.'))
print(root.option_get('foreground', '.'))
print(root.option_get('highlightColor', '.'))
```

gives

> #ffe4c4 
> #e6ceb1
> black
> black

If you need the color for a specific widget class, replace `'.'` by the class name. As mentioned in the comments, if you need the RGB value of the color, you can use `root.winfo_rgb(color)` where `color` is either in HEX format or one of tkinter predefined colors such as black, ... (you can find a list [here](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/colors.htm) for instance).

However, on my computer (I am using Linux and I don't know if the behavior is the same on all platforms) it only works after setting the color scheme to bisque, for the default color scheme it always return `''`.

Comment: Thank you, `root.option_get` is exactly what I needed. I can confirm that it only works with tk_bisque on my platform (manjaro i3) as well.